# Get text from div using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

**Situation**

I'm using Selenium and Python to extract info from a page

Here is the div I want to extract from:

[image]

I want to extract the "Registre-se" and the "Login" text.

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.bet365.com/#/AVR/B146/R^1'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url.format(q=''))

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hm-MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutNarrow_Join ')

for e in elements:
    print(e.text)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hm-MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutNarrow_Login ')

for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

**Problem**

My code don't send any output.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hm-MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutNarrow_Join ">Registre-se</div>
<div class="hm-MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutNarrow_Login " style="">Login</div>
```

Comment: try `get_text()` method on the element

Comment: @GhostOps don't works :/

Comment: try getting the page source and check whether the class name of the html tag differ from the manual inspect of the website

Comment: The class name "hm-MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutMed_Login " only appear in the inspect of the website, but not in the page source. What it's supposed to do now?

Comment: get the page_source of the element and change the class names and try again

Answer (score 0):

By looking this **HTML**

```
<div class="hm-MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutNarrow_Join ">Registre-se</div>
<div class="hm-MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutNarrow_Login " style="">Login</div>
```

and your code, which looks okay to me, except that part you are using `find_elements` for a single **web element.**

and by reading this comment

> The class name "hm-MainHeaderRHSLoggedOutMed_Login " only appear in
> the inspect of the website, but not in the page source. What it's
> supposed to do now?

It is clear that the element is in either **iframe** or **shadow root**.

Cause `page_source` does not look for **iframe**.

Please check if it is in **iframe**, then you'd have to switch to **iframe** first and then you can use the code that you have.

switch it like this :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath here'))
```